# SQL Server, can't check if #temporary table exists, with if else statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, exists, temp-tables

I'm creating a Trigger that handles a temp table (#attributeType). Since the trigger can be called more than once, I wanted to be sure and check if the temp table #attributeType is still there.

This is my code in the trigger body that checks for the temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #attributeType
        SELECT * INTO #attributeType
        FROM attributeType
        PRINT 'IN IF'+   CAST(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') AS NVARCHAR(80))
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO #attributeType
        FROM attributeType
        PRINT 'IN ELSE'+  CAST(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') AS NVARCHAR(80))
    END
```

When I test the code by selecting it with F5 I get this error message, stating that the #attributeType temp table exist:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
There is already an object named '#attributeType' in the database.
```

I know that in stored procedures the #tempTables will be deleted as soon as the sp ends, but still I can't understand why my code is wrong?

N.B.
When I comment out the ELSE block the code works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your test on `OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType')` works fine.  You can test it by running it separately, without a `drop` and `create` in the same batch.

The problem is that SQL Server parses the entire batch before it runs it.  If it knows that `#attributeType` exists it will give an error for:

```
SELECT * INTO #attributeType
```

Even if you drop the table in the previous row.

One solution is to drop the table in a different batch:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #attributeType
GO -- new batch
SELECT * INTO #attributeType ...
```

Another solution is to create the table in a different scope:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #attributeType
exec ('SELECT * INTO #attributeType ...')
```

Comment: @Andomar-is this parsing issue a sort of bug?

Comment: Not a bug, just a degree of primitiveness

Comment: By placing a GO in the body of a Trigger, variables declared before the GO statement are not visibile in the new batch. Guess I'll have to deal with this some how. Placing If clause as the first statement, followed by GO in the trigger body and declare all the variables and all the rest of the code won't split the trigger in 2 batches and make it fail?

Comment: I don't think you can use `go` in a trigger-- the bottom part would just fall out of the trigger definition.  Would a table variable like `declare @tmp table (id int identity, col1 varchar(50))` suit your purpose?

Comment: @Luther: GO cannot be placed in the body of a trigger because it is not a T-SQL statement; GO a batch terminator recognized by SQL Server client tools, and never passed to SQL Server.  I'm not sure why you have 2 different SELECT...INTO statements but that will be problematic.

Comment: @Andomar- well, guess your option of a table variable is way better. I haven't thought about it, I was in tunnel vision with a the #tempTable. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to perform any other operations in IF..ELSE statement, your code can be simplified to the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#attributeType') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #attributeType
END

SELECT *
INTO #attributeType
FROM attributeType
```

In this case you avoid `There is already an object named...` error and you still have temporary table.

Comment: Good job! This may be better than the accepted answer